# Excel Cant scroll down to see sheet tabs

Tags: excel-2007, spreadsheet

I upgraded to office 2007 from 2003 (I think) but now on a couple of documents I cant see all my tabs as the worksheet window goes well below the excel window. I cant move or resize the work sheet window, It's not protected. when I try click on the top bar of the worksheet window - here you would usually be able to drag it around I cant.

however if I select it in full screen mode i can see all the tabs.
I have checked the settings and "show tas" is ticked. I've googled for an hour and tried numerous things but to no avail.
If I try view as tiles It still doesn't change.

My only option left is to copy and past each sheet.. or is there a way to copy a wwhole work sheet tabs and all?

Please help!!

[image: Excel cant see sheet tabs]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to "save as" your document like excel 2007 xlsx format? And stackoverflow.com may be not right site for your question. You can try http://superuser.com/

Comment: Yes no good.. Will move there now . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to double-click the title bar of the worksheet window. This will cause it to Maximize, which will make it fit to the exact size of the application window.

Comment: No double click wont work as the bar is unrespnsive.. I can right click but only get normal options,
Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

Workbook was protected. I went to review tab . took the protect workbook drop down and unselected protect.. worked as normal then!
Hope this helps someone!
Thanks!